# Can't find Point Grey Camera in a new virtual machine

Tags: camera1394, ubuntu, camera, ros-electric, ubuntu-lucid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have used POINT GREY FIREFLY MV FMVU-13S2C digital camera to work on Ubuntu 10.04 and ros electric(I am gonna call it VM1) and it worked very well. But when I install another virtual machine (Ubuntu 10.4 and ros electric also)(I am gonna call it VM2), the camera cannot be found.

I remember the steps that I got the camera worked in VM1 are:

1. install camera drivers by "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-camera-drivers"
2. Create an udev rule for usb adapter to recognize Grey Firefly MV USB camera by "sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/40-pgr.rules" and add the following text into it.

---

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2000", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2001", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2002", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2003", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2004", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2005", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3000", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3001", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3002", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3003", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3004", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3005", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
KERNEL=="raw1394", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
KERNEL=="video1394*", MODE="0664", GROUP="pgrimaging"
SUBSYSTEM=="firewire", GROUP="pgrimaging"
```

---

3. then I follow

---

Install the modules

```
modprobe ohci1394
modprobe video1394
modprobe ieee1394
modprobe raw1394
```

Create proper 1394 devices

```
cd /dev
mknod raw1394 c 171 0
chmod 666 /dev/raw1394
mkdir video1394
cd video1394
mknod 0 c 171 16
mknod 1 c 171 17
chmod 666 /dev/video1394/*
```

Set user paths

```
su user
```

Check for the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It should contain /usr/local/lib. This is necessary to run the applications with the help of the shared libdc1394_cotrol.so.13 object file.

---

I applied exactly same steps to VM2. however, when I run "rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node", camera cannot be found.

Following are some outputs of VM1 and VM2 for your information.

---

```
terminal: lsusb -t
output:

VM1:
1-1:1.0: No such file or directory
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/7p, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0xe0 not yet handled', Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0xe0 not yet handled', Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M

VM2:
1-1:1.0: No such file or directory
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M


terminal: lsusb -t
output:

VM1:

[ INFO] [1357709573.310787186]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1357709573.311007203]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ERROR] [1357709573.311112231]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1357709573.311166747]: Camera calibration file /home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1357709574.475900934]: Found camera with GUID b09d0100b9be53
[ INFO] [1357709574.477526842]: No guid specified, using first camera found, GUID: b09d0100b9be53
[ INFO] [1357709574.478384785]: camera model: Point Grey Research Firefly MV FMVU-13S2C
[ INFO] [1357709574.550290168]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1357709574.550557966]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/00b09d0100b9be53.yaml
[ERROR] [1357709574.550677966]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/00b09d0100b9be53.yaml]
[ WARN] [1357709574.550758075]: Camera calibration file /home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/00b09d0100b9be53.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1357709574.550884432]: [00b09d0100b9be53] opened: 640x480_mono8, 15 fps, 400 Mb/s
[ WARN] [1357709574.943336025]: [00b09d0100b9be53] calibration does not match video mode (publishing uncalibrated data)

VM2:
[ INFO] [1357710156.728287585]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1357710156.728460643]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ERROR] [1357710156.728573663]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1357710156.728643520]: Camera calibration file /home/adrian/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1357710156.871831618]: [camera] exception opening device (retrying): [Camera1394::open]: No cameras found
[ WARN] [1357710156.872580874]: [camera] exception opening device (retrying): [Camera1394::open]: No cameras found
[ERROR] [1357710156.873013311]: [camera] device open failed: [Camera1394::open]: No cameras found
```

Thanks in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51757/can%27t-find-point-grey-camera-in-a-new-virtual-machine/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-09**:
Are you running both VM's at the same time on the same real machine? It is probably not possible for both to connect to a single USB device. Even back-to-back tests might encounter problems with device allocation between the virtual machines.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-09**:
I restart the computer and only open one VM, but it still doesn't work. I noticed that raw1394, ohci1394, video1394,  ieee1394 have been removed once I restart the computer. Is there a way to permanently install these modules?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-09**:
They should get loaded automatically when a 1394 device is detected. The `modprobe` command can load them manually. You can put those commands in `/etc/rc.local`, but it should not be necessary.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-10**:
But in VM2, the modules are not automatically loaded when I plug in the camera. And in VM1, even I didn't plug in the camera, the modules are still there and they won't be removed after restart the VM.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-10**:
And I list the devices of VM1 and VM2. I found VM1 has devices raw1394, v4l and video0 which VM2 doesn't have. I guess video0 is my webcam, I don't know why I even cannot recognize webcam.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-10**:
Ok, I just forgot to connect my webcam to VM2. So it's only raw1394 that VM2 doens't have but VM1 does have.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-10**:
I suspect that it is the "host adapter" that gets allocated to VM1 and triggers those loads. I don't believe that hardware interface can be shared between multiple VM's.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-10**:
I reinstalled the ubuntu on real machine (not virtual). But the problem still exists, there is no raw1394 after I plug in the firewire camera.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-10**:
That sounds like a new problem. Does `dmesg` show the camera? Can `coriander` display it?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-10**:
So I guess it's not raw1394 problem.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-10**:
In VM2, coriander cannot display the camera. dmesg shows too much information, how can I check if it shows the camera?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-13**:
joq, thanks for your patient help. I got it work. I just forgot to give the user permission to access the udev group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution can be found in the answer to another question. http://answers.ros.org/question/48244/unable-to-get-point-grey-usb-camera-work-in-ubuntu/?answer=52116#post-id-52116

---

Originally posted by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) with karma: 441 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-03-22**:
Better consolidate resource and avoid duplicate (for better maintenance). I've replaced all the text with just a link to your answer in another thread.